# MySQL Case Conditions Deduction to generate balance

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table named, "store_update_stock" to store purchase & issue of items. Order status column maintain the states, "purchase" or "issue" when need. Purchase quantity has denoted by plus values (eg:-10) & issue quantity has denoted by minus values (eg:- -2) in the table.

To get the purchase & issue summary I used the following query.

```
SELECT item_id, item_name, order_status, (CASE order_status
        WHEN "issue" THEN store_update_stock_details.qty * (-1)     
        ELSE store_update_stock_details.qty
        END) quantity FROM store_update_stock
```

And generated the expected output as follows :

```
+---------+-----------+--------------+----------+
| item_id | item_name | order_status | quantity |
+---------+-----------+--------------+----------+
|    1000 | A4        | purchase     |       10 |
|    1001 | A3        | purchase     |        5 |
|    1000 | A4        | issue        |        2 |
|    1000 | A4        | issue        |        3 |
|    1001 | A3        | purchase     |        6 |
+---------+-----------+--------------+----------+
```

But I need to get further the balance of each items after performing purchases & issues by modifying the above query and get the output as follows :

```
+---------+-----------+---------+
| item_id | item_name | balance |
+---------+-----------+---------+
|    1000 | A4        |       5 |
|    1001 | A3        |      11 |
+---------+-----------+---------+
```

What can be done in my query to get the desired output. Can anyone helpme ?

Comment: It looks like all you might need is a simple aggregate sum and a group by: `select item_id, item_name, sum(quantity) as balance from store_update_stock group by item_id, item_name` maybe?

Comment: @jpw. That's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like all you might need is a simple aggregate sum and a group by:

```
select item_id, item_name, sum(quantity) as balance 
from store_update_stock 
group by item_id, item_name
```

maybe?